# How to resume the interrupted File upload in ftp using java?

Tags: java, ftp

Hi I'm using the Apache common net jar for FTP upload and download. I need to implement the Resume capability in FTP upload. I referred  so number of websites and articles, but could not find the correct solution. I've attached  my code below.

```
FTPClient client;

public ApacheFtpClient() {
    client = new FTPClient();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApacheFtpClient ftpClient = new ApacheFtpClient();
    ftpClient.upload("myHostAddress", "username", "password", 
                                           "C:\\File.zip", "Rajesh.zip");

}

public void upload(String hostName, String userName,  
                   String password, String fileName, String remoteFileName) {
    try {
        client.connect(hostName);
        client.login(userName, password);
        client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        //This is my Interupted file size in server 
        client.setRestartOffset(158400512); 
        System.out.println("File Upload Started.");
        client.appendFile(remoteFileName, input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // For Download ..

public void download(String hostName, String userName, 
                            String password, String fileName) {
        try {
            client.connect(hostName);
            client.login(userName, password);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            OutputStream outputStream = 
                              new FileOutputStream(new File("local.zip"));
            client.retrieveFile(fileName, outputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to successfully start the restart process ? I am stuck at a very similar issue. Only that I have to download a file from FTP server and for that I have used retrieveFileStream()